# Rust reference from C pointer that is static and mutable?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am writing a C-interfacing library in rust. My API is very C-like: I get "opaque" pointers as a function argument that I must cast into a pointer to my library-internal struct. So the lifetime of the pointer is longer than the function call (static) and the pointer points to mutable data (the library is responsible for initializing and getting/setting this data). Mutability + static data is implicitly part of the API, but in rust I am having trouble (I think with just syntax) stating this.

The code looks like this:

```
struct Real_attr { ... }

pub extern "C" fn attr_init(attr: *mut attr_ptr) -> cty::c_int {
  let p : *mut Real_attr = attr.cast::<Real_attr>();
  let r : &mut Real_attr = p.as_ref::<'static'>().unwrap();
  ...
}
```

Which gives me a error:

```
42 |         p.as_ref::<'static>()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ types differ in mutability
   |
   = note: expected enum `Option<&'static mut Real_attr>`
              found enum `Option<&'static Real_attr>`
```

But I don't understand how to "cast" or otherwise specify that reference to be mutable, adding in the `mut` after static gets me syntax errors..

Comment: "the lifetime of the pointer is longer than the function call (static)" - in general, this is incorrect implication. `'static` lifetime is the lifetime of things which can be held indefinitely, e.g. stored in the thread-local storage until the thread dies. So, strictly speaking, the thing you're doing is unsound.

Comment: @Cerberus So this is a C library and the storage underlying the incoming pointer _can_ come from anywhere: static global variables, thread local storage, heap, stack. The only thing it can't really be is read-only. So my thought was I have to choose the greatest possible lifetime (static). Or would it be more correct to choose the smallest possible lifetime: whatever ensures the pointer does not get dropped when the function returns?

Comment: Yes. Lifetime of the reference is a lower-bound, i.e. it is required to be smaller then lifetime of the data being referenced, so `&'static` can exist only if the underlying data are `'static` itself, i.e. never dropped or moved during the program.

Comment: Got it. So I want to specify a lifetime that is "longer than my function" only-- which is the real implicit API requirement. Off to read that lifetime documentation again..:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a mutable reference, you're looking for [`as_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.as_mut).

```
let r : &mut Real_attr = p.as_mut::<'static>().unwrap();
```